Manim's FuntionGraph to generate the function f(x) = -1/(x**2)
With manim, I tried a simple FuntionGraph for the function

f(X)=-1/(x**2)

The python code is given below
from manim import *

class SimpleFunction(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        graph = FunctionGraph(lambda x: -1/(x**2))
        self.add(graph)

and running it generated the empty png file with no graph.
I tried for an equation f(x) = 1/x and it produced the graph as expected.
Please let me know what is missing here.

You have to create an instance of the class and call the method

What commandline call did you use for manim? The plot works for me.

@user_na I used manim tool as manim -pql simply_function.py
and simply_function.py file has the code.

@user_na  my env:  Ubuntu - 23.04,, python 3.11.6,, manim community v0.18.1
